# How to create a more efficient simulation loop for Monte Carlo in R

Tags: r, loops, simulation, montecarlo, performance

The purpose of this exercise is to create a population distribution of nutrient intake values. There were repeated measures in the earlier data, these have been removed so each row is a unique person in the data frame.

I have this code, which works quite well when tested with a small number of my data frame rows. For all 7135 rows, it is very slow. I tried to time it, but I crashed it out when the elapsed running time on my machine was 15 hours. The `system.time` results were `Timing stopped at: 55625.08 2985.39 58673.87`.

I would appreciate any comments on speeding up the simulation:

```
Male.MC <-c()
for (j in 1:100)            {
for (i in 1:nrow(Male.Distrib))  {
    u2        <- Male.Distrib$stddev_u2[i] * rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
    mc_bca    <- Male.Distrib$FixedEff[i] + u2
    temp      <- Lambda.Value*mc_bca+1
    ginv_a    <- temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
    d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
    mc_amount <- ginv_a + d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
z <- data.frame(
     RespondentID = Male.Distrib$RespondentID[i], 
     Subgroup     = Male.Distrib$Subgroup[i], 
     mc_amount    = mc_amount,
     IndvWeight   = Male.Distrib$INDWTS[i]/100
     )

Male.MC <- as.data.frame(rbind(Male.MC,z))
    }
}
```

For each of the 7135 observations in my dataset, 100 simulated nutrient values are created, then back transformed to the original measurement level (the simulation is using the results from a nonlinear mixed effect model on BoxCox transformed nutrient values).

I would prefer not to use `for` loops, as I read that they are inefficient in `R` but I do not understand enough about options based on `apply` to use those as an alternative. `R` is being run on stand-alone machines, normally this would be a standard Dell-type desktop running a Windows 7 variant, if that influences the recommendations for how to change the code.

Update: To reproduce this for testing,
`Lambda.Value`=0.4 and `Male.Resid.Var`=12.1029420429778 and `Male.Distrib$stddev_u2` is a constant value over all observations.

`str(Male.Distrib)` is

```
'data.frame':   7135 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ RndmEff     : num  1.34 -5.86 -3.65 2.7 3.53 ...
 $ RespondentID: num  9966 9967 9970 9972 9974 ...
 $ Subgroup    : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "3"<"4"<"5"<"6"<..: 4 3 2 4 1 4 2 5 1 2 ...
 $ RespondentID: int  9966 9967 9970 9972 9974 9976 9978 9979 9982 9993 ...
 $ Replicates  : num  41067 2322 17434 21723 375 ...
 $ IntakeAmt   : num  33.45 2.53 9.58 43.34 55.66 ...
 $ RACE        : int  2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ INDWTS      : num  41067 2322 17434 21723 375 ...
 $ TOTWTS      : num  1.21e+08 1.21e+08 1.21e+08 1.21e+08 1.21e+08 ...
 $ GRPWTS      : num  41657878 22715139 10520535 41657878 10791729 ...
 $ NUMSUBJECTS : int  1466 1100 1424 1466 1061 1466 1424 1252 1061 1424 ...
 $ TOTSUBJECTS : int  7135 7135 7135 7135 7135 7135 7135 7135 7135 7135 ...
 $ FixedEff    : num  6.09 6.76 7.08 6.09 6.18 ...
 $ stddev_u2   : num  2.65 2.65 2.65 2.65 2.65 ...
```

`head(Male.Distrib)` is

```
    RndmEff RespondentID Subgroup RespondentID Replicates IntakeAmt RACE INDWTS    TOTWTS   GRPWTS NUMSUBJECTS TOTSUBJECTS  FixedEff stddev_u2
1  1.343753         9966        6         9966      41067 33.449808    2  41067 120622201 41657878        1466        7135  6.089918  2.645938
2 -5.856516         9967        5         9967       2322  2.533528    3   2322 120622201 22715139        1100        7135  6.755664  2.645938
3 -3.648339         9970        4         9970      17434  9.575439    2  17434 120622201 10520535        1424        7135  7.079757  2.645938
4  2.697533         9972        6         9972      21723 43.340180    2  21723 120622201 41657878        1466        7135  6.089918  2.645938
5  3.531878         9974        3         9974        375 55.660607    3    375 120622201 10791729        1061        7135  6.176319  2.645938
6  6.627767         9976        6         9976      48889 91.480049    2  48889 120622201 41657878        1466        7135  6.089918  2.645938
```

Update 2: the line of the function that is causing the `NaN` results is

```
d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
```

Thanks to everyone for their assistance and comments, and also for the speed of responses.

Update: @Ben Bolker is correct that it is the negative `temp` values that are causing the NaN issue. I missed this with some testing (after commenting out the function so that only the `temp` values are returned, and calling my result data frame `Test`). This code reproduces the `NaN` issue:

```
> min(Test)
[1] -2.103819
> min(Test)^(1/Lambda.Value)
[1] NaN
```

But putting the value in as a value and then running the same(?) calculation gives me a result, so I missed this when doing manual calculations:

```
> -2.103819^(1/Lambda.Value) 
[1] -6.419792
```

I now have working code that (I think) uses vectorization, and it is blindingly fast. Just in case anyone else has this issue, I am posting the working code below. I've had to add a minimum to prevent the <0 issue with the calculation. Thank you to everyone who helped, and to coffee. I did try putting the `rnorm` results to a dataframe, and that really slowed things down, creating them this way and then using `cbind` is really quick. `Male.Distrib` is my full data frame of 7135 observations, but this code should work on the cutdown version I posted earlier (not tested).

```
Min_bca <- ((.5*min(Male.AddSugar$IntakeAmt))^Lambda.Value-1)/Lambda.Value
Test <- Male.Distrib[rep(seq.int(1,nrow(Male.Distrib)), 100), 1:ncol(Male.Distrib)]
RnormOutput <- rnorm(nrow(Test),0,1)
Male.Final <- cbind(Test,RnormOutput)
Male.Final$mc_bca    <- Male.Final$FixedEff + (Male.Final$stddev_u2 *     Male.Final$RnormOutput)
Male.Final$temp      <- ifelse(Lambda.Value*Male.Final$mc_bca+1 > Lambda.Value*Min_bca+1,
                           Lambda.Value*Male.Final$mc_bca+1, Lambda.Value*Min_bca+1)
Male.Final$ginv_a    <- Male.Final$temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
Male.Final$d2ginv_a  <- ifelse(0 > (1-Lambda.Value)*Male.Final$temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2),
                           0, (1-Lambda.Value)*Male.Final$temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
Male.Final$mc_amount <- Male.Final$ginv_a + Male.Final$d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
```

Lessons for the day:

- a distribution function does not appear to be resampled in a loop if you try to do what I was trying earlier
- you can't use `max()` the way I tried, as it returns the maximum value from the column, whereas I wanted the maximum from two values. The `ifelse` statement is the replacement one to do.

Comment: I suspect this will reduce to a one-liner using `replicate` and matrix+array math to do all the observations at once. Can you post a small reproducible example, though, so we can give you more concrete advice?

Comment: Growing objects with `rbind()` is very expensive. You can better create an emtpy data frame at the start (e.g. fill it with dummy variables) and fill it in the loop.

Comment: In addition to what @SachaEpskamp said, there's no need for the inner loop.  All the functions you're using are vectorized; take advantage of that.

Comment: I'm agreeing with @JohnColby. I think that either replicate or `boot` from the "boot" package will do the work, and probably be more statistically valid than what your are now doing.

Comment: Depending on what you want the `max(0,...)` to do, you could either use `max(0,...,na.rm=TRUE)` or separately test the `(1-Lambda.Value)` and `temp` components.

Comment: The issue is the back transform method, negative values are fine in the transformed values as these relate to nutrient intakes <1. I'll have a look at the boot package to see if that will help. To be honest, I think much of the issue is that IMO there are some silly low values in the original data - 0.000145 is the minimum. Anything 1 or below causes issues with a Box Cox transform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach that addresses the 2 biggest speed issues:

1. Instead of looping over observations(`i`), we compute them all at once.
2. Instead of looping over MC replications (`j`), we use `replicate`, which is a simplified `apply` meant for this purpose.

First we load the dataset and define a function for what you were doing.

```
Male.Distrib = read.table('MaleDistrib.txt', check.names=F)

getMC <- function(df, Lambda.Value=0.4, Male.Resid.Var=12.1029420429778) {
  u2        <- df$stddev_u2 * rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 1)
  mc_bca    <- df$FixedEff + u2
  temp      <- Lambda.Value*mc_bca+1
  ginv_a    <- temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
  d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
  mc_amount <- ginv_a + d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
  mc_amount
}
```

Then we replicate it a bunch of times.

```
> replicate(10, getMC(Male.Distrib))
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9]    [,10]
[1,] 36.72374 44.491777 55.19637 23.53442 23.260609 49.56022 31.90657 25.26383 25.31197 20.58857
[2,] 29.56115 18.593496 57.84550 22.01581 22.906528 22.15470 29.38923 51.38825 13.45865 21.47531
[3,] 61.27075 10.140378 75.64172 28.10286  9.652907 49.25729 23.82104 31.77349 16.24840 78.02267
[4,] 49.42798 22.326136 33.87446 14.00084 25.107143 25.75241 30.20490 33.14770 62.86563 27.33652
[5,] 53.45546  9.673162 22.66676 38.76392 30.786100 23.42267 28.40211 35.95015 43.75506 58.83676
[6,] 34.72440 23.786004 63.57919  8.08238 12.636745 34.11844 14.88339 21.93766 44.53451 51.12331
```

Then you can reformat, add IDs, etc., but this is the idea for the main computational part. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks John, that does look like the way to go, I've getting `NaN` results for each replicate though, I'm not sure why. It works fine with the test data, and then fails when I run on the full data frame.

Comment: Note that replacing the outer loop by `replicate` is cosmetic -- no speed gain there. The speed gain is from avoiding `rbind` and elementwise operations.

Comment: The only operation in there that could obviously give `NaN` results would be raising negative numbers (`temp`) to fractional powers (`1/Lambda.Value`, `1/Lambda.Value-2`).  Post `summary` results from `Male.Distrib`?

Comment: Oops, you did post the `str` (as good as `summary`).  Your standard deviation is 2.65, so you can expect `u2` to go down to -5 or -6 on a regular basis, which could make `mc_bca`<0 -- although it needs to be <(-2.5) to make `temp` negative.  Anyway, I think this is the direction you should look ...

Comment: @BenBolker Nice tip! Never investigated that myself.

Comment: @Michelle Great I'm glad it's helping. In regards to the NaNs, it might also be more reason to try one of the pre-built packages like DWin suggested, since often these common problems have already been worked through.

Comment: @JohnColby the issue is with the back transformation rather than the replication.

Comment: @Michelle Ahh gotcha. Glad you tracked it down!

Comment: @JohnColby I have fixed my NaN problem and introduced another problem, how can I get replicate to work so that the function returns mc_bca,...,mc_amount? I have added `return(list(mc_bca, temp, ginv_a, d2ginv_a, mc_amount))` to the function, but the replicate doesn't seem to give me correct output.

Comment: @Michelle You might want to use `simplify=F` to get a regular list output. Then you could do something like `sapply(output, '[[', 5)` to get at the `mc_amount` matrix we had before, and so on.

Comment: @JohnColby I'm not familiar with the `sapply` commands at all, would you be able to elaborate more in the example on how I could get a matrix with the additional output? I don't understand enough about the programming to see where this fits in. :(