# Creating a replicate data frame without using rbind, follow on from earlier simulation loop issue

Tags: r, loops, replication

Rather than adding in more comments or making my original question longer, I have created another question. I have received excellent advice in the previous question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009143/how-to-create-a-more-efficient-simulation-loop-for-monte-carlo-in-r)) but I am not good enough in R to implement the suggestions in the comments.

The original code, that took ages, was:

```
Male.MC <-c()
for (j in 1:100)            {
    for (i in 1:nrow(Male.Distrib))  {
        u2        <- Male.Distrib$stddev_u2[i] * rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = 1)
        mc_bca    <- Male.Distrib$FixedEff[i] + u2
        temp      <- Lambda.Value*mc_bca+1
        ginv_a    <- temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
        d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
        mc_amount <- ginv_a + d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
        z <- data.frame(
        RespondentID = Male.Distrib$RespondentID[i], 
        Subgroup     = Male.Distrib$Subgroup[i], 
        mc_amount    = mc_amount,
        IndvWeight   = Male.Distrib$INDWTS[i]/100
        )
        Male.MC <- as.data.frame(rbind(Male.MC,z))
    }
}
```

The `replicate()` answer worked well when I thought I only needed one output (`mc_amount`) from the function:

```
Male.Distrib = read.table('MaleDistrib.txt', check.names=F)

getMC <- function(df, Lambda.Value=0.4, Male.Resid.Var=12.1029420429778) {
      u2        <- df$stddev_u2 * rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 1)
      mc_bca    <- df$FixedEff + u2
      temp      <- Lambda.Value*mc_bca+1
      ginv_a    <- temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
      d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
      mc_amount <- ginv_a + d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
      mc_amount
}
replicate(10, getMC(Male.Distrib))
```

However, even with data corrections made, I am getting unexpected results so I need to be able to see the values for all the interim calculations to determine where I have gone wrong in my logic. This is where I'm stuck. I have created a smaller data frame called `tempdata` for testing, which is just `head()` from my larger dataset of 7135 observations. The `tempdata` set is:

```
    RndmEff RespondentID Subgroup RespondentID Replicates IntakeAmt RACE INDWTS    TOTWTS   GRPWTS NUMSUBJECTS TOTSUBJECTS  FixedEff stddev_u2
1  1.343753         9966        6         9966      41067 33.449808    2  41067 120622201 41657878        1466        7135  6.089918  2.645938
2 -5.856516         9967        5         9967       2322  2.533528    3   2322 120622201 22715139        1100        7135  6.755664  2.645938
3 -3.648339         9970        4         9970      17434  9.575439    2  17434 120622201 10520535        1424        7135  7.079757  2.645938
4  2.697533         9972        6         9972      21723 43.340180    2  21723 120622201 41657878        1466        7135  6.089918  2.645938
5  3.531878         9974        3         9974        375 55.660607    3    375 120622201 10791729        1061        7135  6.176319  2.645938
6  6.627767         9976        6         9976      48889 91.480049    2  48889 120622201 41657878        1466        7135  6.089918  2.645938
```

The updated commands that I am using are:

```
getMC <- function(df, Lambda.Value=0.4, Male.Resid.Var=12.1029420429778) {
    RespondentID <- df$RespondentID
    u2        <- df$stddev_u2 * rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 1)
    mc_bca    <- df$FixedEff + u2
    temp      <- max(Lambda.Value*mc_bca+1,Lambda.Value*Min_bca+1)
    ginv_a    <- temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
    d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
    mc_amount <- ginv_a + d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
    return(list(RespondentID, temp, ginv_a, d2ginv_a, mc_amount))
}
Test <- replicate(10, getMC(tempdata))
```

I get a very nice layout for my calculated variables (`temp`, `ginv_a`, `d2ginv_a`, `mc_amount`) but there are two problems with the results. These problems could be related, I don't understand enough to work out what is happening.

First, I only get 10 columns relating to the first RespondentID, so the function does not seem to be applied to the 6 that are in the dataset.

Second, I get 10 columns, but the `RespondentID` results are concatenated into one cell in each column. If I add `u2` or `mc_bca` to the return list, these are also similarly concatenated into one cell. I have read the `R` help for `return` and it contains this line

> value could be a series of non-empty expressions separated by commas. In that case the value returned is a list of the evaluated expressions, with names set to the expressions where these are the names of R objects.
>   but I don't understand enough about R function programming to know if that is relevant.

I'm hoping there is a quick and obvious fix to this. I have been unable to find a similar problem of which I could copy the solution, all the examples of multiple returns from functions that I have found have used variables being calculated in the function.

I have tried the alternative of creating an empty `data frame` and then trying to vectorize the results into that. I'm worse at vectorizing than I am at replication.

Update: missed the `min_bca` value, which is -2.44478269434376

Comment: Can you give me a link to a sample data file so I can run this?

Comment: @Maiasaura the sample data is copied into the question, above the function.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of more edits, hopefully here is the final solution to your question.

```
    getMC <- function(df, Lambda.Value=0.4, Male.Resid.Var=12.1029420429778,Min_bca=-2.44478269434376) {
            u2        <- df$stddev_u2 * rnorm(nrow(df), mean = 0, sd = 1)
            mc_bca    <- df$FixedEff + u2
            temp      <- pmax((Lambda.Value*mc_bca+1),(Lambda.Value*Min_bca+1))
            ginv_a    <- temp^(1/Lambda.Value)
            d2ginv_a  <- max(0,(1-Lambda.Value)*temp^(1/Lambda.Value-2))
            mc_amount <- ginv_a + d2ginv_a * Male.Resid.Var / 2
            return(data.frame(RespondentID=df$RespondentID,temp=temp, ginv_a, d2ginv_a, mc_amount))
        }

   data=rep(list(tempdata),10) # change 10 to a higher number of replicates
   result_data=llply(data,getMC, .progress = "text")
```

Some notes: I had to troubleshoot your function on a single replicate, line by line, to find out what was wrong (this is something you should do before posting because the question above is not about this issue). `max(vector1,vector2)`returns a single value which makes `temp` the same for all `RespondentID`. Instead I replaced it with `pmax` (see `?max` for an explanation).

Comment: RespondentID looks good, however the values are remaining constant in each set of 6 values in the `V1`, `V2`, etc cells. Does that mean that `u2` and `mc_bca` aren't updating for each row in `testdata`?

Comment: You have no idea how much I appreciate this, I have been trying to get this working for the past 8 hours or so. is this scalable for 7135 rows and 100 replications, which is my ultimate goal?

Comment: Yes, it should be fine. Look into .parallel option for llply (?llply). Also, if you want to summarize the data for the reps inside the function, you can also be more efficient that way (if necessary).

Comment: The values for `temp` etc still aren't incrementing. It appears that the values for 5 of the RespondentIDs are being overwritten as I get 10 sets of different values. +1 for attempt, maybe replicate isn't the right way to go. :(

Comment: Well, I didn't actually evaluate the logic inside your function. Just wanted to solve the issue of getting all the data back in the right format. I'll look around if I have time.

Comment: Also, mic_bca was missing so I just changed that to mc_bca (again, just to make your function work). Changing that might fix your error.